# Return the first non-repeating character of a string

Tags: javascript

In the first chunk of my code I have an ' if ' statement that is not working as it should, and I can't figure out why.

When using the argument 'hous', it should enter the first ' if ' statement and return 0.  It returns -1 instead.

```js
var firstUniqChar = function(s) {

    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
            let letter = s[i];
            // console.log('s[i]: ' + letter);
            // console.log(s.slice(1));
            // console.log( 'i: ' + i);

            if ((i = 0) && !(s.slice(1).includes(letter))) {
                    return 0;
            }
            if ((i = s.length - 1) && !(s.slice(0, i).includes(letter))) {
                    return 1;
            }
            if(!(s.slice(0, i).includes(letter)) && !(s.slice(i + 1).includes(letter))) {
                return 2;
        }
    }
    return -1;
};
console.log(firstUniqChar("hous"));
```

Comment: Single `=` is assignment, not equality, and an assignment of zero is always falsy

Comment: do you want to return a character or a number? what is the meaning of the number?

Comment: Check all of your conditions to use `===` or `==` instead of `=` while comparing in if statements. Eg: `i===0`

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov try `[..."hhoous"].find((c,i,s) => i && c != s[i-1])`

Answer (score 2):

This is another way you can write your function:

```js
const firstUniqChar = s => [...s].filter(c=>!(s.split(c).length-2))[0] || -1;

console.log(firstUniqChar("hous"));
console.log(firstUniqChar("hhoous"));
console.log(firstUniqChar("hhoouuss"));
```

Comment: While balancing between conciseness and performance, you [obviously](https://jsbench.me/x5k9vvp3ib/1) have chosen the former. Nevertheless, even thought I'm not entirely sure how this works, it looks cool. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

#### Look up method for scattered repeated characters and functional `find()`-based approach

---

You may break your input string into array of characters (e.g. using spread syntax `...`) and make use of `Array.prototype.find()` (to get character itserlf) or `Array.prototype.findIndex()` (to get non repeating character position) by finding the character that is different from its neighbors:

```js
const src = 'hhoous',
      
      getFirstNonRepeating = str => 
        [...str].find((c,i,s) => 
          (!i && c != s[i+1]) || 
          (c != s[i-1] && (!s[i+1] || c != s[i+1])))
          
console.log(getFirstNonRepeating(src))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Above will work perfectly when your repeating characters are groupped together, if not, I may recommend to do 2-passes over the array of characters - one, to count ocurrence of each character, and one more, to find out the first unique:

```js
const src = 'hohuso',

      getFirstUnique = str => {
        const hashMap = [...str].reduce((r,c,i) => 
          (r[c]=r[c]||{position:i, count:0}, r[c].count++, r), {})
        return Object
          .entries(hashMap)
          .reduce((r,[char,{position,count}]) => 
            ((count == 1 && (!r.char || position < r.position)) &&
            (r = {char, position}),
            r), {})
      }
        
console.log(getFirstUnique(src))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function nonRepeat(str) {
  return Array
     .from(str)
     .find((char) => str.match(newRegExp(char,'g')).length === 1);
}

console.log(nonRepeat('abacddbec')); // e
console.log(nonRepeat('1691992933')); // 6
console.log(nonRepeat('thhinkninw')); // t
```